# Converting nvarchar to datetime and back into database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was handed a table where the Date column was loaded as nvarchar(50).

I more or less figured out converting it into datetime.

```
select convert(datetime, Date_Time_In, 101)
FROM [DB].[dbo].[table]
```

But I get a issue where it does not drop the Time portion of the column. Also how would I go about putting that back into the table, or just converting in the table with a specific sql code. This database has about 30 million rows and over 160 columns.

The end goal is trying to sort my data since I try to use the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[table]

  WHERE Date_Time_In between '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' and '4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM'
```

And it just queries back all the dates.

---

*Queries when I convert into datetime format 101

[image] After<----------------> Before   [image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to drop the time portion? Then convert to a date? And please don't stick this back in the database as a string. Fix the structure of the database and store data using the correct datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the time portion, use

```sql
CONVERT(datetime, Date_Time_In, 111)
```

To replace the original column, create a new column, populate it with converted dates, rename the original column, assign the original name to the new column.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the date as a string, date functions won't work. Full stop. You have text, not dates.

In order to create the illusion that you have dates so that you can use date functions, you would have to do something horrible like this (which will run forever because the `WHERE` predicate is non-SARGable due to the function call):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  [DB].[dbo].[table]

WHERE 
  CONVERT(DATETIME, Date_Time_In, 101) 
    BETWEEN '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AND '4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM';
```

Better solutions would be:

1) Fix the data type on the current column (I know; legacy system, quite a few records, and so forth, making this unlikely, but if you can do it, WOO HOO!)

or

2) Add column number 161 as a *persisted* computed column that is actually a `DATETIME`

```
ALTER TABLE [DB].[dbo].[table]
ADD DateTimeIn AS TRY_PARSE(Date_Time_In AS DATETIME) PERSISTED;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you need to cast both sides of the comparison to the same date type.

The long answer is you need to fix the underlying structure of that table. Data types are super important and storing everything as a "string" is just going to cause problems down the road when someone wants to report on that data. I hope that the following example helps to illustrate the point. First look at what happens to the timestamp as it gets cast or converted to the different types. Then look at what happens as those types are used in the comparison. Better would be to store the timestamp not as an NVARCHAR(50) but as a DATETIME, DATETIME2, or DATE depending on how accurate you need to be.

```
SELECT CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) betweenStart, 
       CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) betweenEnd
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenStart, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME, '4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenEnd
-- betweenStart              betweenEnd
-- 2019-01-01 13:00:00.000  2019-04-01 13:00:00.000

SELECT CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME2) betweenStart, 
       CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME2) betweenEnd
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenStart, 
       CONVERT(DATETIME2, '4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenEnd
-- betweenStart              betweenEnd
-- 2019-01-01 13:00:00.0000000  2019-04-01 13:00:00.0000000

SELECT CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATE) betweenStart, 
       CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATE) betweenEnd
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenStart, 
       CONVERT(DATE, '4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM', 101) betweenEnd
-- betweenStart              betweenEnd
-- 2019-01-01                2019-04-01

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #t
    END
CREATE TABLE #t(
    myIdCol INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Date_Time_In NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO #t
VALUES('10/24/2018 12:52:10 PM'), 
('10/26/2018 3:53:45 PM'), 
('10/26/2018 3:53:45 PM'), 
('1/1/2019 3:53:45 PM'), 
('4/1/2019 12:59:00 PM'), 
('4/1/2019 01:00:01 PM')

SELECT * FROM #t WHERE Date_Time_In BETWEEN '1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AND '4/1/2019 
01:00:00 PM'
--  myIdCol   Date_Time_In
--  1   10/24/2018 12:52:10 PM
--  2   10/26/2018 3:53:45 PM
--  3   10/26/2018 3:53:45 PM
--  4   1/1/2019 3:53:45 PM
SELECT * 
FROM #t 
WHERE CAST(Date_Time_In AS DATETIME) BETWEEN 
      CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME) 
      AND 
      CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME)
--  myIdCol Date_Time_In
--  4   1/1/2019 3:53:45 PM
--  5   4/1/2019 12:59:00 PM
SELECT * 
FROM #t 
WHERE CAST(Date_Time_In AS DATETIME2) BETWEEN 
      CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME2) 
      AND 
      CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATETIME2)
--  myIdCol Date_Time_In
--  4   1/1/2019 3:53:45 PM
--  5   4/1/2019 12:59:00 PM
SELECT * 
FROM #t 
WHERE CAST(Date_Time_In AS DATE) BETWEEN 
      CAST('1/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATE) 
      AND 
      CAST('4/1/2019 01:00:00 PM' AS DATE)
--  myIdCol Date_Time_In
--  4   1/1/2019 3:53:45 PM
--  5   4/1/2019 12:59:00 PM
--  6   4/1/2019 01:00:01 PM
```